# Spring @Transactional usage on wrapper method

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, transactional

Do I need to add @Transactional annotation to second method? I think not, but really not sure.

```
@Transactional
public void addUser(User u) {
    u.setCreationDate(new Date());
    userDAO.addUser(u);
}

// should I add @Transactional annotation here?
public User addUser(String name, String surname) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setName(name);
    user.setSurname(surname);
    this.addUser(user);
    return user;
}

// DAO method
public void addUser(User u) {
    entityManager.persist(u);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `@Transactional` annotation to the `public User addUser(String name, String surname)` method other wise the method will execute in a non transactional way.

`@Transactional` uses proxy mechanism to implement transactional support, it will be invoked only when you call the method from a second object (ie If you call a method within the same class it will not go through the proxy system so it will always run using the callers transaction).

Answer (score 1):

Both are different method as signature is diff, hence needs to add @Transactional annotation.
As you knows spring is working on proxy object

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to annotate the wrapper methods if you are using default 
`@Transactional` settings. The `PROPAGATION` settings in `@Transactional` defines
transactional scope. The default propagation setting is `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED`.

Refer [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-propagation) for more details.

Comment: I just tried it in application, second method not works without @Transactional annotation.

Comment: What do you mean by second method not working? Are you getting any errors? what is the behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

In your case it will produce similar result. The difference is if you put @Transactional on `public User addUser(String name, String surname)` you will be creating a new user under context of a transaction. If you don't -- a transaction will only start when your code executes `public void addUser(User u)`

Comment: I just tried it in application, second method not works without @Transactional annotation.

Comment: In that case you need to give us your userDAO code. Depending on how you implement it, the outcome might be different

Comment: userDAO.addUser(User u){ entityManager.persist(u); }